# Use a value to use in another entry field Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
lbl3 = Label(top, text='Percent:',font=('Helvetica',10))
percent = IntVar()
entry3 = Entry(top,textvariable=percent)
```

So I want to input a percentage value into entry3 in TOP and use this percentage later in ROOT as such:

```
var = IntVar()
e1 = Entry(root, text=var)
var.set(percent.get())
```

However once I run the script the value is already set at 0 and if i change it and move over to root value there is also 0 , however i want to be able to modify the value in TOP and use that in root. How do i do this?

Comment: Please provide a testable example. There is not enough here to work with accurately. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suspect your `var.set(percent.get())` is only ran at the start of your code and this is why all you see is zero in `e1`. In order for your 2nd var to update you need to either tie an even to the entry field to update the other var or use the same `IntVar()` on both entry fields.